# mysql Entity Framework with Distinct

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, distinct

Good evening, I'm two days trying to solve this problem and got nothing. I am suspicious that it is a bug, could someone help me? I am getting the following error message.

> Unknown column 'Distinct1.nCdSite' in 'where clause'
>
> [MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'Distinct1.nCdSite' in
>   'where clause']  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket() +501 
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetResult(Int32& affectedRow,
>   Int64& insertedId) +450 
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32 statementId, Boolean
>   force) +136  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult() +1269
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +2528 
>   MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior) +22  .  .  .

I have the following code:

Model:

```cs
[Table("pagina")] 
public class pagina 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public long nCdPagina { get; set; } 
    public long nCdVisitante { get; set; } 
    public string sDsUrlReferencia { get; set; } 
    public string sDsPalavraChave { get; set; } 
    public string sDsTitulo { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("nCdVisitante")] 
    public visitante visitante { get; set; } 
} 

public class retorno 
{ 
    public long Key { get; set; } 
    public int Online { get; set; } 
} 

[Table("site")] 
public class site 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public long nCdSite { get; set; } 
    public string sDsTitulo { get; set; } 
    public string sDsUrl { get; set; } 
    public DateTime tDtCadastro { get; set; } 
} 

[Table("visitante")] 
public class visitante 
{ 
    [Key] 
    public long nCdVisitante { get; set; } 
    public long nCdSite { get; set; } 
    public string sDsIp { get; set; } 
    public DateTime tDtCadastro { get; set; } 
    public DateTime tDtAtualizacao { get; set; } 

    [ForeignKey("nCdSite")] 
    public site site { get; set; } 
}
```

Query:

```cs
return (from pag in this.context.pagina.Include("visitante").Include("site") 
    group pag by pag.visitante.nCdSite into g 
    select new retorno 
    { 
        Key = g.Key, 
        Online = g.Select(e => e.visitante.sDsIp).Distinct().Count() 
    }).ToList<retorno>();
```

The problem only occurs when I place `Distinct()`. `Count()` if let alone works perfectly.

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083627/linq-mysql-group-by-year-month-day-select-year-month-day-count). Seems that the query provider has a hard time creating correct sub queries. Did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: I contacted mysql and it really is a bug and have reported it as such.
http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=68513